# ios swift parse: no results matched the query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I pin username and password to the local datastore and on app start I want to check if its available. Therefore I do a

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"LocalUser")
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.whereKeyExists("username")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {....
```

When I run the app, I get the error:
no results matched the query

Why do I get this as error?
Why can I not handle a "nothing found" in the }else{ Statement?

I mean, a empty result is not so unusual?

What I want to achieve, is that no local user data was found, send the user to the login viewController. But as long as I get this kind of error I can't do that.

Is there maybe another way to check if local store data exists?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

try using findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock instead of getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock to see if u have data present or not.

It is also pointed here :https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-pfquery-getfirstobjectinbackgroundwithblock-error-when-no-results

Answer (score 0):

PFUser.CurrentUser gets the user logged in from disk. No need for your async call.